# group nested array by same value php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I need to create new array from and nested array where minimul one of the child array have the same value or are repeated.

I have tried to check inside an foreach to compare the child array id, if its found previous but seems not work right.

```
$finalJobs = array();

       foreach ($CompleteJobs as $index => $jobs) {
            foreach ($jobs['jobs'] as $job) {

                if (!empty($finalJobs)) {
                    foreach ($finalJobs as &$finalJob) {
                        foreach ($finalJob['jobs'] as $Fjob) {
                           if (!empty(array_intersect($Fjob, $job))) {
                             //here is my problem
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    $finalJobs[$job['id']] = $job;
                }

            }
        }
```

This is my original array, i need to if in child array `jobs` the `id` is doubled or repeated.

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => array:4 [▼
    "id" => 9
    "position" => 3
    "jobs" => array:2 [▼
      0 => array:21 [▼
        "id" => 2
        "name" => "9987C"
        "plan_id" => null
      ]
      1 => array:21 [▼
        "id" => 3
        "name" => "1009V"
        "plan_id" => null
      ]
    ]
  ]
  1 => array:4 [▼
    "id" => 8
    "position" => 2
    "jobs" => array:1 [▼
      0 => array:21 [▼
        "id" => 2
        "name" => "10bb"
        "plan_id" => null
      ]
      1 => array:21 [▼
        "id" => 4
        "name" => "CC09"
        "plan_id" => null
      ]
    ]
  ]
  ...
```

My expected array have to look like:

```
array:4 [▼
   8 => array:4 [▼
     "id" => 8
     "position" => 2
   ]
    "id" => 9
    "position" => 3
    "jobs" => array:3 [▼
      0 => array:21 [▼
        "id" => 2
        "name" => "01"
        "plan_id" => null
      ]
      1 => array:21 [▼
        "id" => 3
        "name" => "09BB"
        "plan_id" => null
      ]
      3 => array:21 [▼
        "id" => 4
        "name" => "10CB"
        "plan_id" => null
      ]
    ]
  ]
```

I need to have sort of union where i check if same `id` value is found and the rewrite the array to the new form.

Comment: You say your previous code *but seems not work right* - can you add this code as it may be easy to fix, but as yet we don't know what you have tried.

Comment: I dont get the expected result, here it seems like you just want all the job moved to item with id 9, but what about the first entry?